# Python opencv security camera window crashs

Tags: python, opencv

I am trying to write a program with python using opencv library to create a security camera that detect faces and movements.

CODE :

```
import cv2
import time
import datetime

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0, cv2.CAP_DSHOW)

while True:
    _, frame = cap.read()

    cv2.imshow("Security Camera", frame)

    if cv2.waitKey(1) == ord('q'):
        break
    
    cap.release()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

When i try to run the code i get this error message after the camera window opens and crashes within a second :

ERROR MESSAGE :

> C:/Users/DELL/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python39/python.exe
> e:/coding/python/cv2-sec/main.py Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "e:\coding\python\cv2-sec\main.py", line 10, in 
> cv2.imshow("Security Camera", frame) cv2.error: OpenCV(4.5.3) C:\Users\runneradmin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-req-build-sn_xpupm\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\color.cpp:182:
> error: (-215:Assertion failed) !_src.empty() in function
> 'cv::cvtColor'

I tried all possible solutions available online with no luck.
please support if possible.
thnx.

Comment: check `cap.isOpened()` once and check `ret, frame = cap.read(); if not ret: break`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this:

```
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
cap.set(3,640) # Width
cap.set(4,480) # Height

while True:
    ret, img = cap.read()

    cv2.imshow('video',img)

    if cv2.waitKey(1) == ord('q'):
        break
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: it worked ! what was going wrong ??

Comment: this question is an obvious duplicate and should be flagged as such, but not answered.